# js code component not loading properly while scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, components

this is my js code which i am using in my html page.

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
function drawComponent(x, y, square, circleRadius) {
    ctx.strokeRect(square[0] + x, square[1] + y, square[2] - square[0], square[3] - square[1]);
    const w = circleRadius*2
    const circles = [
        [square[0] - w + x, square[1] - w + y, square[0] + w + x, square[1] + w + y],
        [square[2] - w + x, square[1] - w + y, square[2] + w + x, square[1] + w + y],
        [square[0] - w + x, square[3] - w + y, square[0] + w + x, square[3] + w + y],
        [square[2] - w + x, square[3] - w + y, square[2] + w + x, square[3] + w + y]
    ];
    circles.forEach(circle => {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc((circle[0] + circle[2]) / 2, (circle[1] + circle[3]) / 2, circleRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
        ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.lineWidth = 1;
        ctx.stroke();
    });
    const [squareCenterX, squareCenterY] = calculateCenter([square[0] + x, square[1] + y, square[2] + x, square[3] + y]);
    createLabel('Headline', squareCenterX, squareCenterY - circleRadius * 1.5, 'bold', '20px', 'black');
    createLabel('Text', squareCenterX, squareCenterY + circleRadius * 1.5 + 10, 'normal', '16px', 'gray');
}
function createLabel(text, left, top, fontWeight, fontSize, color) {
    const label = document.createElement('label');
    label.textContent = text;
    label.style.position = 'absolute';
    canvas.parentNode.appendChild(label);
    label.style.left = left - label.offsetWidth / 2 + 'px';
    label.style.top = top - label.offsetHeight / 2 + 'px';
    label.style.fontWeight = fontWeight;
    label.style.fontSize = fontSize;
    label.style.textAlign = 'center';
    label.style.color = color;
}
function calculateCenter(rect) {
    const x1 = rect[0];
    const y1 = rect[1];
    const x2 = rect[2];
    const y2 = rect[3];
    return [(x1 + x2) / 2, (y1 + y2) / 2];
}
const componentWidth = 100;
const componentHeight = 100;
const circleRadius = componentWidth * 0.1;
for (let row = 0; row < 8; row++) {
    for (let col = 0; col < 10; col++) {
        const x = col * componentWidth * 1.5; 
        const y = row * componentHeight * 1.5; 
        const square = [50, 50, 150, 150];
        drawComponent(x, y, square, circleRadius);
    }
}
```

i want the output to display many such components in a grid format [sample component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOCVz.png)

the code is giving me [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrPUP.png)

but when i am scrolling down the square border and circles are disapppearing [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lGOs.png)

I don't know if anything is wrong in the code or is it a loading or browser issue. please help me out

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your canvas is set to the window/*viewport* width and height, not the height of all the components.  Any stroke displayed outside the canvas will be cut off.

Since you are hardcoding a specific number of rows and columns of components, you could compute the combined width and height of all components before displaying them, then set your canvas to those dimensions.

For example, move your width/height declarations up top, then set the canvas width/height based on the number of rows and cols (these could also be made variables set up top)

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const componentWidth = 100;
const componentHeight = 100;
canvas.width = componentHeight * 1.5 * 10;
canvas.height = componentHeight * 1.5 * 8;
```

Comment: got it thank you